# Blank images React Native ios simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios-simulator

I'm using RN 0.61.5, after updating to latest version of XCode (12.0) faced with next problem - on iOS simulator (iOS 13.5, iOS 14.0) all images (local and loaded over http/https) are blank. Here is example of using local images

```
const source = require('../Assets/Images/Images/logo/logo_white.png');
<Image style={styles.image} width={90} height={90} source={source} />
```

and images loaded over https

```
<Image style={styles.image} width={90} height={90} source={{uri: 'https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png'}} />
```

I can see all images with inspector, it's show blank image with width and height

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Hi, please take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29215) on GitHub. I was experiencing this strange behavior, but just using the iOS simulator. In production it should be ok.

Comment: @Milore man, you save my life! many thanks, patch from github issue is worked :)

Answer (score 1):

This [patch](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29215#issuecomment-657201612) helped me to solve my pr

Comment: I used this method mention in that same thread - worked for me: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29215#issuecomment-712772968